# Retrieving IMEI number and mac id in splash activity and use it throught the program

Tags: android

I have to retrieve mac id and imei number and use them throughout the program how should I do it??

I tried to declare them as static and public but I was told it was not a good procedure.

Help me.

Comment: So are you asking how to retrieve the IMEI, or how to store it in a variable that you can use throughout your application?

Comment: yes i tried to declare them as public and static, it worked but I need another workaround like using sharedpreferences

Answer (score 2):

For **Mac ID** use following example:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager .getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress= wifiInfo .getMacAddress();
```

For **IMEI** use following example:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
telephonyManager .getDeviceId();
```

Following permissions, you need to add in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE "/>
```

If you want to use these later-on then you can store these in **SharedPreferences**

To write into **SharedPreferences** use following code:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("MAC_ID", macAddress);
editor.commit();
```

To get stored value from **SharedPreferences** use following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
String macAddress = sharedPreferences.getString("MAC_ID", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..while retrieving i am getting this error:  PREFS_NAME cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: This is a dummy text, here you need to put your preference name which you would declare as `Constant` in a Utility class.

Comment: I am a newbie..do we do it like this in Splash??
 public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "VALUES_PREFS";

Comment: You are right but we should declare this globally for entire project.
Because we need to access the `SharedPreferences` again with same key.

Comment: I did it in my splash globally still getting the same error

Comment: You should use `MY_PREFS_NAME` instead of `PREFS_NAME` then.

Comment: ya man..did the same with MY_PREFS_NAME..still the same..should I add the MY_PREFS_NAME param while editing like:
getPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

Comment: This code is executing effortlessly at my end.
You need to start debugging my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

To Extract IMEI of Android device, use TelephonyManager

```
TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
mngr.getDeviceId();
```

Add Permissions in you manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

To Store: Use Shared Preference.
Setting and Extracting String values from shared pref:

```
private SharedPreferences getSetting(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("Preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp;
}

 /**
 * Setting shared preferences
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @param value
 */
 private void setString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSetting(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Extract String from shared Preference
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @return String
 */
private static String getString(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSetting(context);
    String value = sp.getString(key, null);
    return value;
}
```

I hope it will work for you, Feel free to ask in case of query.

Comment: thanks for the response can u please tell me how to use store and retrieve the sharedpeferences